# Use a json in a java class

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am trying to use this JSON data in a java class to retrieve data like: question1 and its answers:

```
    "questions": [
        {
            "question1": "Nos exemplos abaixo, pode-se nomear variáveis:",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer1": "&Alexandre"
                },
                {
                    "answer2": "65Alexandre"
                },
                {
                    "answer3": "professor alexandre"
                },
                {
                    "answer4": " profAlexandre"
                }
            ],
            "certa": "D"
        },
        {
            "question2": "Como é possível adicionar um comentário ao código em Python? ",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "//"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "#"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "/"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "--"
                }
            ],
            "certa": "B"
        },
        {
            "question3": "Assinale a alternativa que demonstre o código que leia dois valores e some-os, em python :",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "x1 = int(input('Digite um valor: '))\nx2 = int(input('Digite outro valor: '))\np = x1 + x2\nprint('A some entre {} e {}, resulta em {}'.format(x1, x2, p)) "
                },
                {
                    "answer": "x1 = input('Digite um valor: '))\nx2 = input('Digite outro valor: '))\np = x1 + x2\nprint('A some entre {} e {}, resulta em {}'.format(x1, x2, p))"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "public class x {\n    public static void main(String args[]) {\n        System.out.println('Olá Mundo!');\n    }\n}"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "public class perguntas {\n    public static void main(String args[]) {\n        int x1;\n        int x2;\n        int p;\n        p = x1 + x2;\n        System.out.println(p);\n    }\n }"
                }
            ],
            "certa": "A"
        },
        {
            "question4": "Escolha a alternativa que demonstre o código, em python, que leia um número e escreva seu dobro e seu triplo :",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "n = int(input('Digite um valor: '))\ndobro = n * 2\ntriplo = n * 3\nprint('O dobro do valor digitado equivale a {}'.format(dobro))\nprint('O triplo do valor escrito vale {}'.format(triplo))"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "n = str(input('Digite um valor: '))\ndobro = n * 4\n triplo = n * 7\nprint('O dobro do valor digitado equivale a {}'.format(dobro))\nprint('O triplo do valor escrito vale {}'.format(triplo))"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "import javax.swing.JOptionPane;\npublic class perguntas2 {\n    public static void main (String args[]) {\n        int num;\n        num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 'Digite um valor: '));\n        int dobro;\n        int triplo;\n        dobro = num * 2;        \n triplo = num * 3;\n       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 'O dobro do número digitado é '  + dobro + 'e o triplo é ' + triplo);\n    }\n } "
                },
                {
                    "answer": "public class olamund {\n    public static  void main (String args[]){\n        int n1;\n        int n2;\n        System.out.println('Olá mundo!'); \n    }\n}"
                }
            ],
            "certa": "A"
        },
        {
            "question5": "Como será mostrado o resultado do código em Python a seguir: \np = float(input('Qual é o preço do produto? R$ ')) \nd = p-(p*5/100) \nprint('O produto que custava R${:.2f}, na promoção com desconto de 5% vai custar R${:.2f}'.format(p,d)) ",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "Não mostrará nenhum resultado  "
                    
                },
                {
                    "answer": "Um resultado com 3 números após o ponto  "
                },
                {
                    "answer": "Um resultado com 2 números após o ponto "
                },
                {
                    "answer": "O cálculo errado do desconto"
                }
            ],
            "certa": "C"
        },
        {
            "question6": "Qual será o resultado do código em Python a seguir: \nnome = input('Qual o seu nome? ') \nprint(nome) ",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "O código não irá funcionar pois falta “;” no final de cada linha.  "
                },
                {
                    "answer": "O código não irá mostrar o nome digitado pelo usuário.  "
                },
                {
                    "answer": "O usuário não conseguira digitar o nome. "
                },
                {
                    "answer": "O código irá mostrar o nome digitado pelo usuário.  "
                }
            ],
            "certa": "D"
        },
        {
            "question7": "Assinale a alternativa que possui p código, em python, que escolha dois números aleatórios que some-os ou multiplique-os, no caso se o usuário digitar 's', ele fará a soma, senão ele apertará 'm', que multiplicará os números.",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "import random\nn1 = random.randint(0, 100)\nn2 = random.randint(0, 100)\ns = n1 + n2\nm = n1 * n2\nresultado = (input('Digite (s) para somar dois valores ou (m) para mutiplicar: '))\nif (resultado == 's'):\n    print(f'{n1} + {n2} = {s}')\nelse : #(m)\n    print(f'{n1} * {n2} = {m}')"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "import javax.swing.*;\nimport java.util.Random;\npublic class p4 {\n    public static void main (String[] args) {\n        Random r =  new Random();\n        int s, m, resultado;\n        int n1 = r.nextInt(99)+1;\n        int n2 = r.nextInt(99)+1;\n        s = n1 + n2;\n        m = n1 * n2;\n        resultado = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 'Digite 1 para somar dois valores ou 2 para multiplicá-los'));\n        if (resultado == 1) {\n            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 'A soma de ' + n1 + ' + ' + n2 + ' é igual a ' + s);\n        }\n        else {\n            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 'O produto de ' + n1 + ' * ' + n2 + ' é igual a' + m);\n        }\n    }\n}"
                     
                },
                {
                    "answer": "import random\n\nn = 10\nfor i in range(100):\n    print(n)"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "import numpy\n\ni = 150\nif i = True\n   print('Acertou!')"
                }
            ],
            "certa": "A"
        },
        {
            "question8": "Quantas vezes a letra a é impressa pelos seguintes comandos?\n\nfrase = 'Vou arrasar na prova!'\nfor i in range(len(frase)):\n    if i % 2 == 0:\n        print(frase[i])",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "0"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "1"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "2"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "3"
                }
            ],
            "certa": "B"
        },
        {
            "question9": "O que é impresso pelo trecho de código a seguir?\n uma_lista = [1, 3, 5]\nprint(uma_lista * 3)",
            
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "[1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5]"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "[1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5]"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "[3, 9, 15]"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "[1, 3, 5, 3]"
                }
            ],
            "certa": "A"
        },
        {
            "question10": "Qual valor é exibido pelo seguinte comando: \nprint(int(53.785))",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "Nada, é produzido um erro de execução."
                },
                {
                    "answer": "53"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "54"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "53.785"
                }
            ],
            "certa": "B"
        },
        {
            "question11": "O que o seguinte código imprime? \nif (4 + 5 == 10):\n    print('Verdadeiro')\nelse:\n    print('Falso')",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "Nada"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "Verdadeiro\nFalso"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "Verdadeiro"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "Falso"
                }
            ],
            "certa": "D"
        },
        {
            "question12": "O que o seguinte código imprimirá se x = 3, y = 5 e z = 2? \nif x < y and x < z:\n    print('a')\nelif y < x and y < z:\n    print('b')\nelse:\n    print('c')",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "a"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "b"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "c"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "Nada"
                }
            ],
            "certa": "C"
        },
        {
            "question13": "O tipo atribuído a variável x será: \nx = input('x: ')",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "String",
                    "correct": true
                },
                {
                    "answer": "Int"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "Float"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "Boolean"
                }
            ],
            "certa": "A"
        },
        {
            "question14": "O que é impresso pelo trecho de código a seguir?\n\numa_lista = [3, 67, 'gato', [56, 57, 'gato'], [ ], 3.14, False]\nprint(3.14 in uma_lista, end=' ')\nprint(57 in uma_lista)",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "False False"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "False True"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "True False"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "True True"
                }
            ],
            "certa": "C"
        },
        {
            "question15": "Na linguagem de programação Python, o método que permite verificar se uma string começa com alguns caracteres é o:",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "return"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "startswith"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "len"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "count"
                }
            ],
            "certa": "B"
        }
    ]
    
}
```

I haven't found the best way to rescue this data yet, so if anyone knows any way to rescue this data in an efficient and optimized way it will be of great help.

But I am not able to pull up a particular question or answers, I have only been able to pull that so far: **{"answers":[{"answer":"&Alexandre"},{"answer":"65Alexandre"},{"answer":"professor alexandre"},{"answer":" profAlexandre"}],"question1":"Nos exemplos abaixo, pode-se nomear variáveis:","certa":"D"}** I used iterator to get this informations!

Thanks,
Rafael Bidetti

Comment: Take a look at [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2591098/12567365) - there are currently 59 answers there - and probably many other similar questions, which may also help. Otherwise, you can [edit] your question to show us your code, what you have tried, and where you are stuck. Don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask] for more background and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [JsonObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) to parse the data out of your JSON. An easy way is to safe the data in an `arrayList` and after that you can do whatever you want with it.

the following code could help you with this I think:

```
                            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            for (int i=0; i<response.length(); ++i) {
                                String info = "";
                                JSONObject o = null;
                                try {
                                    info += response.getJSONObject(i).getString("answer");
                                    responsList.add(info);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), it is a powerful tool made by Google which helps you to easily work with JSON. You can use its methods like `toJson()` and `fromJson()` and it will create a Java object as you desire.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [JsonCreator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson_annotations/jackson_annotations_jsoncreator.htm) can help you fine tune how you deserialize the object